# Javascript error while unzipping a file

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am trying this following code to unzip a file. 
But it's showing error in the line of ActiveXObject.
Error is: ActiveXObject does not have a constructor.
What does that mean? What is missing in the code?

```js
var zipfile="Somefile.zip";
var extractpath="E:\\Test";
unzip(zipfile,extractpath);

function unzip(zipfile,extractpath){
     var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
     var oShell = new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application');
     var dst,zip;
     dst = shell.NameSpace(fso.getFolder(extractpath).Path);
      zip = shell.NameSpace(fso.getFile(zipfile).Path);
      for (var i=0; i<zip.Items().Count; i++) {
           try {
            if (fso.FileExists(zipfile)) {
                WSH.Stdout.Write('Unzipping ' + zip.Items().Item(i) + '... ');
                dst.CopyHere(zip.Items().Item(i), 4 + 16);
                WSH.Echo('Done.');
            }
        }
        catch(e) {
            WSH.Echo('Failed: ' + e);
        }
    var zipfile = WSH.Arguments(0),
dest = zipfile.replace(/\.\w+$/, '\\');

unzip(zipfile, dest);
          
          }
//~ var op=oShell.namespace(extractpath)    ;
//~ var ip=oShell.namespace(zipfile);
//~  op.CopyHere((ip.Items), 4)
    }
```

Comment: Please ignore the commented part.

Comment: Is there not a single person in the forum to help me with this?